# how to override existing wordpress Bookly plugin file

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I want to some changes in existing bookly plugin file but no effected to original one but when i have try to override plugin template and put into the wordpress theme directory but its not work.

This is my plugin file which I have made some changes but I dont know how to override in my theme directory.

plugins/bookly-responsive-appointment-booking-tool/backend/components/dialogs/appointment/edit/Ajax.php

And i have put this directory like this

wp-content/themes/themify-ultra-child/bookly-responsive-appointment-booking-tool/backend/components/dialogs/appointment/edit/Ajax.php

```
public static function getDataForAppointmentForm()
    {
        $type = self::parameter( 'type', false ) == 'package'
            ? Lib\Entities\Service::TYPE_PACKAGE
            : Lib\Entities\Service::TYPE_SIMPLE;

        $statuses = Lib\Proxy\CustomStatuses::prepareAllStatuses( array(
            Lib\Entities\CustomerAppointment::STATUS_PENDING,
            Lib\Entities\CustomerAppointment::STATUS_APPROVED,
            Lib\Entities\CustomerAppointment::STATUS_CANCELLED,
            Lib\Entities\CustomerAppointment::STATUS_REJECTED,
            Lib\Entities\CustomerAppointment::STATUS_WAITLISTED,
            Lib\Entities\CustomerAppointment::STATUS_DONE,
        ) );
        $status_items = array();
        foreach ( $statuses as $status ) {
            $status_items[ $status ] = Lib\Entities\CustomerAppointment::statusToString( $status );
        }

        $result = array(
            'staff'                    => array(),
            'customers'                => array(),
            'start_time'               => array(),
            'end_time'                 => array(),
            'app_start_time'           => null,  // Appointment start time which may not be in the list of start times.
            'app_end_time'             => null,  // Appointment end time which may not be in the list of end times.
            'week_days'                => array(),
            'time_interval'            => Lib\Config::getTimeSlotLength(),
            'status'                   => array(
                'items' => $status_items,
            ),
            'extras_consider_duration' => (int) Lib\Proxy\ServiceExtras::considerDuration( true ),
            'extras_multiply_nop'      => (int) get_option( 'bookly_service_extras_multiply_nop', 1 ),
        );

        // Staff list.
        $staff         = Lib\Entities\Staff::query()->findOne();
        $staff_members = $staff ? Lib\Config::proActive() ? Lib\Utils\Common::isCurrentUserSupervisor() ? Lib\Entities\Staff::query()->sortBy( 'position' )->find() : Lib\Entities\Staff::query()->where( 'wp_user_id', get_current_user_id() )->find() : array( $staff ) : array();
        $postfix_archived = sprintf( ' (%s)', __( 'Archived', 'bookly' ) );

        $max_duration  = 0;
        $has_categories = (bool) Lib\Entities\Category::query()->findOne();

        foreach ( $staff_members as $staff_member ) {
            $services = array();
            if ( $type == Lib\Entities\Service::TYPE_SIMPLE ) {
                $services = Proxy\Pro::addCustomService( $services );
            }
            foreach ( $staff_member->getStaffServices( $type ) as $staff_service ) {
                $sub_services = $staff_service->service->getSubServices();
                if ( $type == Lib\Entities\Service::TYPE_SIMPLE || ! empty( $sub_services ) ) {
                    if ( $staff_service->getLocationId() === null || Lib\Proxy\Locations::prepareStaffLocationId( $staff_service->getLocationId(), $staff_service->getStaffId() ) == $staff_service->getLocationId() ) {
                        if ( ! in_array( $staff_service->service->getId(), array_map( function ( $service ) { return $service['id']; }, $services ) ) ) {
                            $category = Lib\Entities\Category::find( Lib\Entities\Service::find( $staff_service->getServiceId() )->getCategoryId() );
                            $services[] = array(
                                'id'              => $staff_service->service->getId(),
                                'title'           => sprintf(
                                    '%s (%s)',
                                    $staff_service->service->getTitle(),
                                    Lib\Utils\DateTime::secondsToInterval( $staff_service->service->getDuration() )
                                ),
                                'category'        => $category ? $category->getName() : ( $has_categories ? __( 'Uncategorized', 'bookly' ) : ''),
                                'duration'        => $staff_service->service->getDuration(),
                                'units_min'       => $staff_service->service->getUnitsMin(),
                                'units_max'       => $staff_service->service->getUnitsMax(),
                                'locations'       => array(
                                    ( $staff_service->getLocationId() ?: 0 ) => array(
                                        'capacity_min' => Lib\Config::groupBookingActive() ? $staff_service->getCapacityMin() : 1,
                                        'capacity_max' => Lib\Config::groupBookingActive() ? $staff_service->getCapacityMax() : 1,
                                    ),
                                ),
                            );
                            $max_duration = max( $max_duration, $staff_service->service->getUnitsMax() * $staff_service->service->getDuration() );
                        } else {
                            array_walk( $services, function ( &$item ) use ( $staff_service ) {
                                if ( $item['id'] == $staff_service->service->getId() ) {
                                    $item['locations'][ $staff_service->getLocationId() ?: 0 ] = array(
                                        'capacity_min' => Lib\Config::groupBookingActive() ? $staff_service->getCapacityMin() : 1,
                                        'capacity_max' => Lib\Config::groupBookingActive() ? $staff_service->getCapacityMax() : 1,
                                    );
                                }
                            } );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $locations = array();
            foreach ( (array) Lib\Proxy\Locations::findByStaffId( $staff_member->getId() ) as $location ) {
                $locations[] = array(
                    'id'   => $location->getId(),
                    'name' => $location->getName(),
                );
            }
            $result['staff'][] = array(
                'id'        => $staff_member->getId(),
                'full_name' => $staff_member->getFullName() . ( $staff_member->getVisibility() == 'archive' ? $postfix_archived : '' ),
                'archived'  => $staff_member->getVisibility() == 'archive',
                'services'  => $services,
                'locations' => $locations,
                'category'  => Lib\Proxy\Pro::getStaffCategoryName( $staff_member->getCategoryId() ),
            );
        }

        /** @var Lib\Entities\Customer $customer */
        // Customers list.
        foreach ( Lib\Entities\Customer::query()->sortBy( 'full_name' )->find() as $customer ) {
            $name = $customer->getFullName();
            if ( $customer->getEmail() != '' || $customer->getPhone() != '' ) {
                // $name .= ' (' . trim( $customer->getEmail() . ', ' . $customer->getPhone(), ', ' ) . ')';
                     // $name .= ' (sdsfd)';

                     // echo '<pre>',print_r($customer->getCity()),'</pre>';
                $name .= ' ('.trim($customer->getStreet().', ' .$customer->getPostcode()).')';
            }

            $result['customers'][] = array(
                'id'                 => $customer->getId(),
                'name'               => $name,
                'status'             => Lib\Proxy\CustomerGroups::prepareDefaultAppointmentStatus( get_option( 'bookly_gen_default_appointment_status' ), $customer->getGroupId() ),
                'custom_fields'      => array(),
                'timezone'           => Lib\Proxy\Pro::getLastCustomerTimezone( $customer->getId() ),
                'number_of_persons'  => 1,
            );
        }

        // Time list.
        $ts_length  = Lib\Config::getTimeSlotLength();
        $time_start = 0;
        $time_end   = max( $max_duration + DAY_IN_SECONDS, DAY_IN_SECONDS * 2 );

        // Run the loop.
        while ( $time_start <= $time_end ) {
            $slot = array(
                'value' => Lib\Utils\DateTime::buildTimeString( $time_start, false ),
                'title' => Lib\Utils\DateTime::formatTime( $time_start ),
            );
            if ( $time_start < DAY_IN_SECONDS ) {
                $result['start_time'][] = $slot;
            }
            $result['end_time'][] = $slot;
            $time_start += $ts_length;
        }

        $days_times = Lib\Config::getDaysAndTimes();
        $weekdays  = array( 1 => 'sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', );
        foreach ( $days_times['days'] as $index => $abbrev ) {
            $result['week_days'][] = $weekdays[ $index ];
        }

        if ( $type == Lib\Entities\Service::TYPE_PACKAGE ) {
            $result = Proxy\Shared::prepareDataForPackage( $result );
        }

        wp_send_json( $result );
    }
```

Does not override the plugin in theme folder.

Comment: You can't override it unless they don't want you to. Most plugins instance will be singleton, also they may have disabled cloning of instance. if these are case then your only option is to take backup of original file and replace it with yours. If they don't have these conditions you can access instance of plugin or clone and override with your class

Comment: is there any solution for override some changes

Comment: Like i said only if developer added filters and hooks you can add/update functions, if not only way is to take backup of original file and replace with your own

Answer (score 0):

Even one year after this question, [Bookly](https://www.booking-wp-plugin.com/) still doesn't allow customizations (like almost everyone do in Wordpress Development).

As an example, you can try to search every use of important functions used to this propose like `do_action`, and you'll not find more than 20 results, which is extremely low for a plugin of this size - and most occurrences are related to [`wpml_register_single_string`](https://wpml.org/wpml-hook/wpml_register_single_string/) hook.

A [topic](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/override-templates-10/) opened a few months ago also says this, answered by Bookly.